# What is this fungus/lichen in my Garam Masala? (“Trifle”/truffle?)

Tags: spices, indian-cuisine, food-identification

I just bought a lovely bag of Garam Masala, and was all ready to grind some when I got home!  But when I opened it, I found something I didn’t recognise — at first I thought something had gone mouldy, but there’s enough of this in there that whatever it is, I presume it’s supposed to be in there.

[image: Picture of the strange fungus]

It looks to me like a fungus or lichen of some sort.  The list of ingredients includes “trifle” — could that be a mis-spelling for some Indian species of truffle, perhaps?

Comment: That's just weird. I agree with Doug below that it looks like a wood ear or cloud ear, but what it would be doing in garam masala, I can't imagine! I don't believe either of those fungi have any common use in Indian cuisine. Where did you buy this garam masala? I'd be somewhat disinclined to eat it just based on the oddness.

Comment: I bought it at a small local Indian grocery store — it’s not a super-shiny sort of place, but I’ve not had any bad experiences there — they don’t routinely sell out-of-date items or anything.  It’s Nirav brand — not the store’s home-made mix or something.

Comment: Actually, you found an ingredient that is considered extremely hard to find among fans of indian cooking outside india!

Answer (score 25):

It seems to be an **edible lichen**.  It looks very like one described online as **(black) stone flower** in English and **dagad phool** in Hindi, which seems to be a not uncommon ingredient in various spice mixes; e.g. on the left in this photo from [an Indian food blog](http://www.nandyala.org/mahanandi/archives/2007/10/07/dagad-phool-kala-elachi-badal-phool-and-naagkeshar/):

[**Edit:** photo removed as I’ve just realised the author of that blog specifically requests not redistributing their content.  It’s a nice photo + site, though, if you follow the link!]

Having found these names, it’s now not hard to find a lot of websites mentioning it, especially in blogs/forum threads; but I can’t find any site in English that gives much detailed information.  Even its purpose in the mix is a bit unclear: some blog commenters describe it as having a unique earthy, mushroom-y flavour; others, as being similar to star anise; Wikipedia even [seems to suggest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethnolichenology#Lichens_for_food) it might just be a bulking agent.  (I don’t get any particular scent off it, at least not dry.)

So I think this is probably the right identification; and I’m reassured that it’s not something wrong with the mix; but I’m still quite intrigued, and would love to hear more about this ingredient from someone who knows it better!

Comment: That's fascinating! I'm glad you found your answer.

Answer (score 12):

This spice is called "Kalpaasi" in Tamilian cuisine. 
I use it in my chicken gravy, mutton gravy and for few vegetarian recipes too. 
I use kalpasi when I season some of my chutney varieties. 
It releases a strong curry smell the moment you add it in hot oil. 
This spice grows inside water wells absorbing pure air (from what I heard from my aunt when I was very young). 
If you made Biryani and wondered why you're not getting that "Restaurant Biriyani smell", it means you missed putting some "Kalpasi" when you prepared it. 
If you wanted to try a distinctive **Tamilnadu gravy using kalpasi**: http://cooking.jingalala.org/2012/12/pakoda-kulambu-recipe-chettinadu-pakoda-kuzhambu-south-indian-style-gravy-varieties/

Comment: http://cooking.jingalala.org/what-is-kalpasi-what-is-dagad-phool-2/

Comment: Also "Kalpassi" transliterates to "foot-level moss/foot algae". (Not to be confused with any sort of foot fungus). if it grows in a well, I can definitely see that the name, paasi usually is used to indicate slimy algae growing on wet rocks or near wells.

Answer (score 10):

Just found out from a friend..its also called Kalpasi or Kallupachi (literally Stone Flower / Moss) in Telugu and is a not so commonly used spice in Chettinad cuisine. So, probably it is not the very generic garam masala (which is more common in the Northern part of India than the South) but something very specific to use in certain dishes, say like the Punjabi Garam Masala. Also hear that it is used in Goda masala, something more common in the Western parts of India (goan and maharashtrian cooking).

Answer (score 6):

This is an edible lichen which is commonly used in Indian spice mixture especially curry masala. I am using this everyday in my kitchen. it gives a very pleasant smell to the curry. About 100gm of this lichen is added to make 750 gm of curry masala powder. Around 10gm of curry masala powder is added to one liter of curry (this is apporximate quantity but it is in this range) so you can imagin how littel quantity is required.

Answer (score 3):

At first I thought those were wood ears, but checking around, they look more like cloud ears.  In answer to your question, yes, they are a fungus/mushroom that grows on the sides of trees.  I've always cooked with them in Chinese cooking.  As for the trifle, I haven't found any connection between wood ears, cloud ears and the word trifle, although depending on who was doing the translation, as you note, truffle could have become trifle, and cloud ears and truffles are both fungi (although the similarity stops there).

Comment: Thankkyou!  Hmmm… looking around, though, the photos of cloud/wood ears I can find online don’t look quite like this thing — this is more like a lichen and less like a mushroom.  I’ve never had cloud/wood ears, though, so I’m not sure…

Comment: Ah — after some more thorough googling than I’d done at first, I think I’ve found it online after all: it is an edible lichen, sometimes called “stone flower”, and can apparently be a reasonably standard component of garam masala.  Will put what I’ve found into a separate answer.  Thankyou for your help, though, in any case!

Answer (score 3):

The full name is lichen stone flower, in Indian it has many names as, patthar ke phool/dagad phool/kalpasi, and mostly used in North India, Goa and Maharashtra. It is used particularly in kabab dishes namely galauti kabab, kakori kabab and many other dishes, maharashtrian goda masala also have it. It is found in foothills of himalaya mountain, after monsoon, locals collect it and sell/supply.

Answer (score 3):

Yes , black stone flower , a lichen / moss , which only grows where the air is absolute pure . It disappears when pollution starts . I had never known one could use it in food before seeing it in a Hyderabadi grocery . I had used it for natural dying years ago , and the amazing thing was that wool dyed with this moss keeps the forest smell for years .This inspired me towards a  special rice dish ; rice in rice-cooker with half water , half rose or orange-blossom-water , hand full black stone flower , cinnamon sticks , star anise orange and lemon peel .... The smell filling the house is unbelievable , as the taste .

Comment: You're using orange blossom water for *half* the water volume in your cooker?  Either you've got pretty poor-quality blossom water, or it must smell like a perfume bomb just went off.  Sounds a bit intense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a biryani at a Marathis friend's home and the taste was incredible. He mentioned that he used a fungus, specific to his region. For years I had looked for the name and never found it till finally I came across dagad phool randomly. Even Indians are mostly not aware of this - a very region specific spice.

Answer (score 0):

छडिला किंवा दगड फुल हलबा सावजी यां लोकांना गरम मसाला used in purely non-vegetarian dishes. This type of food famous in Vidarbha region. [image: छडिला दगड फुल (algae)]

Answer (score -2):

Dagad Phool: http://www.mamtaskitchen.com/board/showthread.php?thread_id=9512